# Scheduler problems and zombiejobs without session-ID

Tags: database, oracle, zombie-process, dbms-scheduler, dbms-job

We are running a small staging setup on an Oracle Database (11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0). We are running jobs using both timed and event-based schedules and our issue is regarding the scheduling.

This setup has been running for about two years now, but we suddenly started experiencing problems with the event-based scheduling. The schedules just didn't start. We don't know if it is the events that didn't fire or just the schedule that didn't work, but none of the jobs that starts on these schedules started.

We tried to resolve the problem by dropping and recreating a schedule, but this resulted in zombie-jobs being created from the jobs already running, that depended on this schedule. These zombie-jobs have no session-ID and even our DBA doesn't know how to kill them. Even our workaround - creating new jobs and schedules, doesn't work - they just don't run. The DB has been restarted a couple of times, which should clear all caches, but this didn't solve anything and our zombie-jobs also survives restarting the DB.

Our DBA has created a ticket at Oracle Support, but they have so far not provided a solution - nor any workaround. They told us that this problem apparently is undocumented.

Questions:

1. How do we get the event-based scheduling up and running again?
2. How do we kill the zombie-jobs - as far as I know, there's no "decapitate"-function. :(

Comment: how do you see these jobs? anything in the alert log of the database?

Comment: We can see them in the all_scheduler_running_jobs view. The zombie-jobs distinct themselves by having no session_id.

Comment: what happens if you try: exec dbms_scheduler.stop_job('job_name');

Comment: It throws this exception:
ORA-27468: "0." is locked by another process
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 199
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 557
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: Using the force-option throws the same exception.

Comment: show parameter job_queue_processes
alter system set job_queue_processes=0;
try stopping the job again.
alter system set job_queue_processes=old_value;

Comment: as the last resort, try to kill process CJQn processes at os level.

Comment: Our DBA tried alter system set job_queue_processes=0; - didn't work.

Comment: Our DBA has also tried to restart the server, which should take care of killing the processes at OS level. :)

Comment: So you haven't got any CJQ processes at OS level?

Comment: I'm not a sys-adm, but I think a reboot of the physical server kills all running processes, right?

Comment: it should but as long as you still have a process locking your job, you should verify this is the case.

Comment: We're not sure if it is a locking problem, but thankyou very much for your time and efforts. :)

Comment: Oracle Support are going to be unhelpful because you're using an obsolete version of the product, and not even patched to the terminal release, at that. Lifetime support only covers patching of known issues on terminal release version, unless you pay extra for the premium service.